# Snapshots vs. clones in Btrfs

Tags: filesystems, btrfs

What is the difference between a clone and a snapshot in Btrfs?

I read [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20151104121511/http://www.linux.org/threads/intro-to-snapshot-cloning.4119/) (original [here](http://www.linux.org/threads/intro-to-snapshot-cloning.4119/)) that the only difference is that snapshot is read-only while clone allows for reading and writing.

I haven't found a confirmation of this anywhere else, could you please tell me if this is a reliable fact? Thanks!

Comment: Link is dead/fails to open due to server error.

Comment: @KarlRichter Link replaced with link to the Internet Archive, which had a copy of the page.

Comment: There’s no such thing as a “clone” in BTRFS. The linked article is just splitting hairs.

Answer (score 0):

`man btrfs subvolume` is your fried:

> A btrfs snapshot is much like a subvolume, but shares its data(and
>          metadata) with other subvolume/snapshot. Due to the capabilities of
>          COW, modifications inside a snapshot will only show in a snapshot but
>          not in its source subvolume.

That means that a snapshot isn't necessarily read-only (-> reference can't be right or is outdated (from 2013)). It can be though when specified.

By cloning I assume you mean using `btrfs send`. It is used to transfer a btrfs subvolume on another machine. This exists simply because you can only create a snapshot on the same btrfs. You wouldn't use it on the same machine/btrfs.

Comment: Note that the linked article is from mid-2013. Lots has happened in btrfs development in the last three years.

Comment: https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Manpage/btrfs-subvolume Here’s the up-to-date man page.